# How to pass arguments onClick of Button in react-admin?

Tags: reactjs, react-admin

I want to show the id of a user in `console` when someone clicks the button. However, it is not showing. I am using `react-admin`. This is my code:

```
import { List, Datagrid, TextField, Button } from 'react admin';

function ShowData(id) {
 console.log(id);
}

export const UserList = props => {

  return (
    <>
    <List>
           <Datagrid>
                <TextField source="id" />
                ....
                <Button label="Click" onClick={ShowData} value={record => record.id} />
           </Datagrid>
    </List>
    </>
  )
};
```

Comment: Where is the data coming from (FormData). If you are passing it via Props make sure it is present.

Answer (score 1):

`<Button>` does not support the `value` prop. And your `onClick` handler, defined outside the button component, won't have access to the current record.

You should write a wrapper around the Button that grabs the record from the `RecordContext`:

```
import { Button, useRecordContext } from 'react-admin';

export const TestButton = (props) => {
   const record = useRecordContext();
   const handleClick = () => {
      console.log(record);
   );
   return <Button onClick={handleClick} {...props} />;
};
```

You can learn more about the `useRecordContext` hook in the Fields documentation:

https://marmelab.com/react-admin/Fields.html#writing-your-own-field-component